# Getting null and error when fetching data using reftofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem, using the Kotlin programming language.
and I've made a model for the response. But why when I call the response it has a null result. Previously I had two method calls with different responses.
how so that I can read the data or retrieve the data list. do I need to modify my data model?

```
{
    "Message": "Success",
    "Type": 100,
    "MetaData": {
        "Count": 3271
    },
    "SponsoredData": [
        {
            "CoinInfo": {
                "Id": "939621",
                "Name": "STC",
                "FullName": "Student Coin",
                "Internal": "STC",
                "ImageUrl": "/media/37746407/student.png",
                "Url": "/coins/stc/overview",
                "Algorithm": "N/A",
                "ProofType": "N/A",
                "Rating": {
                    "Weiss": {
                        "Rating": "",
                        "TechnologyAdoptionRating": "",
                        "MarketPerformanceRating": ""
                    }
                },
                "NetHashesPerSecond": 0,
                "BlockNumber": 0,
                "BlockTime": 0,
                "BlockReward": 0,
                "AssetLaunchDate": "2020-06-25",
                "MaxSupply": -1,
                "Type": 1,
                "DocumentType": "Webpagecoinp"
            }
        }
    ],
 "Data": [
        {
            "CoinInfo": {
                "Id": "1182",
                "Name": "BTC",
                "FullName": "Bitcoin",
                "Internal": "BTC",
                "ImageUrl": "/media/37746251/btc.png",
                "Url": "/coins/btc/overview",
                "Algorithm": "SHA-256",
                "ProofType": "PoW",
                "Rating": {
                    "Weiss": {
                        "Rating": "B+",
                        "TechnologyAdoptionRating": "A-",
                        "MarketPerformanceRating": "C+"
                    }
                },
                "NetHashesPerSecond": 157822528995934930000,
                "BlockNumber": 703183,
                "BlockTime": 506,
                "BlockReward": 6.25,
                "AssetLaunchDate": "2009-01-03",
                "MaxSupply": 20999999.9769,
                "Type": 1,
                "DocumentType": "Webpagecoinp"
            },
            "RAW": {
                "IDR": {
                    "TYPE": "5",
                    "MARKET": "CCCAGG",
                    "FROMSYMBOL": "BTC",
                    "TOSYMBOL": "IDR",
                    "FLAGS": "514",
                    "PRICE": 678586773.79,
                    "LASTUPDATE": 1633171876,
                    "MEDIAN": 677469500,
                    "LASTVOLUME": 0.010353,
                    "LASTVOLUMETO": 6999984.243,
                    "LASTTRADEID": "1633171876186",
                    "VOLUMEDAY": 49.32770503999994,
                    "VOLUMEDAYTO": 33482329502.91773,
                    "VOLUME24HOUR": 149.41556718,
                    "VOLUME24HOURTO": 100887877163.5413,
                    "OPENDAY": 684964988.95,
                    "HIGHDAY": 686549502.79,
                    "LOWDAY": 675234434.08,
                    "OPEN24HOUR": 671211678.75,
                    "HIGH24HOUR": 688066111.68,
                    "LOW24HOUR": 662631219.9,
                    "LASTMARKET": "Luno",
                    "VOLUMEHOUR": 1.4619014100000014,
                    "VOLUMEHOURTO": 992280645.4632988,
                    "OPENHOUR": 678161517.3,
                    "HIGHHOUR": 679695229.88,
                    "LOWHOUR": 678140219.45,
                    "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOUR": 149.41556718,
                    "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOURTO": 100887877163.5413,
                    "CHANGE24HOUR": 7375095.039999962,
                    "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": 1.0987733487794238,
                    "CHANGEDAY": -6378215.160000086,
                    "CHANGEPCTDAY": -0.9311738939792252,
                    "CHANGEHOUR": 425256.49000000954,
                    "CHANGEPCTHOUR": 0.06270725765937081,
                    "CONVERSIONTYPE": "direct",
                    "CONVERSIONSYMBOL": "",
                    "SUPPLY": 18822156,
                    "MKTCAP": 12772466115812090,
                    "MKTCAPPENALTY": 0,
                    "CIRCULATINGSUPPLY": 18822156,
                    "CIRCULATINGSUPPLYMKTCAP": 12772466115812090,
                    "TOTALVOLUME24H": 233620.31552885583,
                    "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": 158531152656004.97,
                    "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24H": 233292.54456234566,
                    "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24HTO": 158308731613298.78,
                    "IMAGEURL": "/media/37746251/btc.png"
                }
            },
            "DISPLAY": {
                "IDR": {
                    "FROMSYMBOL": "Ƀ",
                    "TOSYMBOL": "IDR",
                    "MARKET": "CryptoCompare Index",
                    "PRICE": "IDR 678,586,773.8",
                    "LASTUPDATE": "Just now",
                    "LASTVOLUME": "Ƀ 0.01035",
                    "LASTVOLUMETO": "IDR 6,999,984.2",
                    "LASTTRADEID": "1633171876186",
                    "VOLUMEDAY": "Ƀ 49.33",
                    "VOLUMEDAYTO": "IDR 33,482,329,502.9",
                    "VOLUME24HOUR": "Ƀ 149.42",
                    "VOLUME24HOURTO": "IDR 100,887,877,163.5",
                    "OPENDAY": "IDR 684,964,989.0",
                    "HIGHDAY": "IDR 686,549,502.8",
                    "LOWDAY": "IDR 675,234,434.1",
                    "OPEN24HOUR": "IDR 671,211,678.8",
                    "HIGH24HOUR": "IDR 688,066,111.7",
                    "LOW24HOUR": "IDR 662,631,219.9",
                    "LASTMARKET": "Luno",
                    "VOLUMEHOUR": "Ƀ 1.46",
                    "VOLUMEHOURTO": "IDR 992,280,645.5",
                    "OPENHOUR": "IDR 678,161,517.3",
                    "HIGHHOUR": "IDR 679,695,229.9",
                    "LOWHOUR": "IDR 678,140,219.5",
                    "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOUR": "Ƀ 149.42",
                    "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOURTO": "IDR 100,887,877,163.5",
                    "CHANGE24HOUR": "IDR 7,375,095",
                    "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": "1.10",
                    "CHANGEDAY": "IDR -6,378,215",
                    "CHANGEPCTDAY": "-0.93",
                    "CHANGEHOUR": "IDR 425,256",
                    "CHANGEPCTHOUR": "0.06",
                    "CONVERSIONTYPE": "direct",
                    "CONVERSIONSYMBOL": "",
                    "SUPPLY": "Ƀ 18,822,156.0",
                    "MKTCAP": "IDR 12,772,466.12 B",
                    "MKTCAPPENALTY": "0 %",
                    "CIRCULATINGSUPPLY": "Ƀ 18,822,156.0",
                    "CIRCULATINGSUPPLYMKTCAP": "IDR 12,772,466.12 B",
                    "TOTALVOLUME24H": "Ƀ 233.62 K",
                    "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": "IDR 158,531.15 B",
                    "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24H": "Ƀ 233.29 K",
                    "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24HTO": "IDR 158,308.73 B",
                    "IMAGEURL": "/media/37746251/btc.png"
                }
            }
        },
}
```

Methode 1:

```
private fun getDataCoints() {
    NetworkConfig().getDataCoinss.getDataCoinss().enqueue(
        object : Callback<List<ResponseCoin>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ResponseCoin>>, response: Response<List<ResponseCoin>>) {
                Log.d("jajal 2", "Berhasil")
                val respon = response.body()!!
                val cek = respon[0].message.toString()
                name.text = cek

                Log.d("jajal 2", "jajal " + response)
             


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ResponseCoin>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Failure", "Fialed jajal: " + t.message)
                name.text = t.message
            }
        }
    )
}
```

this response print method 1

`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Method 2 :

````
  private fun getDataCoints() {
        NetworkConfig().getDataCoinss.getDataCoinss().enqueue(
            object : Callback<ResponseCoin>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseCoin>, response: Response<ResponseCoin>) {
                    Log.d("jajal 2", "Berhasil")
                    val respon = response.body()!!
                    val cek = respon.toString()
                    name.text = cek

                    Log.d("jajal 2", "jajal " + respon.toString())


                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseCoin>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Failure", "Fialed jajal: " + t.message)
                    name.text = t.message
                }
            }
        )
    }```


this response 2 :

```(type=null, message=null, metaData=null, hasWarning=null, data=null, sponsoredData=null) ```
````

Comment: Hey, can you share the model class, i.e "ResponseCoin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@indriyanto Nugroho I see your JSON data have something missing. used postman then calls API and gets JSON data. go to this website [1]: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.this website will help you the more easy way. you can easy way build a response model class. [2]: https://jsonformatter.org/